# How to do a md5 hash of some hex values?

Tags: php, hex, md5

I'm a newbie in php. what i need to do is to do md5 hashing on some hex values. For example, I want to do an md5 hash of 0x14. the actual hash of that, is:

```
15f41a2e96bae341dde485bb0e78f485
```

but i can not reproduce that in PHP.

```
md5 (0x14);
```

Doesn't work, even

```
md5(chr(hexdec(14)));
```

doesn't work. cause its not an actual character

I tried every possibility that i could think of, searched countless hours on the Internet, still nothing. How can i make this work?

Comment: note that `0x14` is not the same as `'0x14'` - the former is a single character, the latter is a 4-char string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write binary values into any [double quoted string with the hexadecimal escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), maybe this helps ([Demo](http://codepad.org/QqW5M3h2)):

```
md5("\x14"); # 15f41a2e96bae341dde485bb0e78f485
```

Comment: i feel like a dumb seeing all this solutions and I couldn't find any on my own. using \x14 is very interesting. thank you

Comment: Thanks to you and the link you provide, i don't need to convert the octal value to hex first. the actual value that i wanted to do md5 hashing on, was \024 . which beautifully works by issuing md5("\024");

Comment: Good to see it was a pointer in the right direction. You can only know what you know, stupidity is to stop learning only :)

Answer (score 4):

```
php> echo md5(chr(0x14))
15f41a2e96bae341dde485bb0e78f485
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

`md5(chr(0x14));` //15f41a2e96bae341dde485bb0e78f485

Answer (score 2):

[hexdec](http://php.net/hexdec) takes a string, so your example would work if you quote the '14'

```
md5(chr(hexdec('14')));
```

alternatively, you could use a [hexadecimal numeric literal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

```
md5(chr(0x14));
```